# Removing Borders in Page Block Table

Tags: visualforce

I am not able to remove the default border which appears on using Page Block Table.Do you guys have any CSS code by which it can be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS (see e.g. [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)):

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="cs">

<style>
table.list {
    border-width: 0 !important;
}
tr.dataRow.last td {
    border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
} 
</style>

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cs}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.Birthdate}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

removes the single pixel grey border if that is what you mean:

[image: Example of no border]

Comment: Hey Thanks this partially solved my problem but there is still a grey line between each table rows which I want to get rid of.Is there any CSS code for the same?

Comment: @DebarunSengupta Change `tr.dataRow.last` (matches the `tr` that has both the `dataRow` and `last` class) to `tr.dataRow`.